# How to initialize Multiple List<string> by using a given name List<string>

Tags: c#, string, list, dictionary

Is there a function I can use to initialize Multiple List by using a given name List?
For example:

```
List<string> nw_TCList = new List<string>();
List<string> ia_TCList = new List<string>();
List<string> st_TCList = new List<string>();
List<string> ud_TCList = new List<string>();
List<string> mb_TCList = new List<string>();
```

I would like to create thoese List, right now i have a List contains thoese name:

```
List<string> myNameList = new List<string>() 
{
    "nw_TCList", 
    "ia_TCList", 
    "st_TCList", 
    "ud_TCList", 
    "mb_TCList" 
};
```

I want to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myNameList.Count(); i++)
{
   List<string> myNameList[i] = new List<string>();
}
```

Furthermore, Assume I have a dictionary `myDic<sting,List<string>>`, i have a Key list `List<string> myKeys` and many `List<string>` that i just created. I want to add them to the Dictionary something like this:

```
myDic.Add(myKeys[0], nw_TCList);
myDic.Add(myKeys[1], ia_TCList);
myDic.Add(myKeys[2], st_TCList);
myDic.Add(myKeys[3], ud_TCList);
myDic.Add(myKeys[4], mb_TCList);
```

Is there any easy way to do this job?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you need to create them before adding them to the dictionary?

Comment: Probably getting rid of all the `xx_TCList` variables in the first place is the way to go. Why do you have those?

Comment: you want their local *variable names* to assume their design-time name from a list of strings? are you after code generation, reflection, ... probably it is sufficient to add anonymous list instances to the dictionary and always access them by key.

Comment: @john before or after are both ok, i would like to know different ideas ; )

Comment: May be what you need is some object with Two properties?

Comment: @ZeZhang Well you can't really dynamically generate variables - I'm not sure how you would use them even if you could. (`dynamic` with `ExpandoObject` does exist, but it's essentially a glorified dictionary)

Comment: @CodeCaster My goal is to create this dictionary `myDic<sting,List<string>>` in here, i need many `List<string>` inside

Comment: It's weird that the variable name hold valuable information.. pretty sure it's some kind of X/Y

Comment: @dlatikay That's probably a good direction, i will try that for the dictionary see if it fit my case : ) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get rid of all the extra declared lists and collect them in the dictionary. If you have already all names in a list that you can use as the key, you can create a dictionary with empty lists and the corresponding keys using the [ToDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

```
List<string> myNameList = new List<string>() 
{
    "nw_TCList", 
    "ia_TCList", 
    "st_TCList", 
    "ud_TCList", 
    "mb_TCList" 
};

Dictionary<string, List<string>> myDictionary = myNameList.ToDictionary
       (
           key => key, // this means that the current element in myNameList will serve as the key
           value => new List<string>() // this means that for the current element in myNameList a new List<string> will be created as the value
       );
```

Now you can access the lists the following way:

```
List<string> nw_TCList = myDictionary[myNameList[0]];
```

EDIT:

A little more robust approach would be to use an `enum` for the names. This way you could have the compiler to check for spelling. Declare an enum:

```
public enum ListNames
{
    nw_TCList,
    ia_TCList,
    st_TCList,
    ud_TCList,
    mb_TCList
}
```

An now use it as the Key in the dictionary. Now the construction of the dictionary looks a little different. You can get all values of the enum using the [Enum.GetValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Enum_GetValues_System_Type_) method.

```
Dictionary<ListNames, List<string>> myDictionaryRobust = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ListNames))
                             .Cast<ListNames>()
                             .ToDictionary(key => key, value => new List<string>());
```

Using this approach, the next time you think, that you need more of those lists, simply extend your enum, and the dictionary will be filled automatically with an extra list and the correct name!

Comment: Typo missing `//` . near value =>. With the 6 char edit rules i can't fix it ^^

Answer (score 3):

You could loop over the names and add an entry to the dictionary accordingly:

```
foreach(var name in new []{ "list", "names", "here" })
{
  myDic[name] = new List<string>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's same with `foreach` but in one line

```
var myDic = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>()
List<string> myKeys = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3"};
myKeys.ForEach(l => myDic.Add(l, new List<string>));
```